# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given on line 6

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['hash'])&&!empty($_GET['hash'])){
        $hash = $_GET['hash'];
        $message_query = "SELECT from_id, message FROM message WHERE hash='$hash'";
        $run_messages = mysqli_query($con,$message_query);
        while($row_messages = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$run_messages)){
             $form_id = $row_messages['from_id'];
             $message = $row_messages['message'];

             $user_query = "SELECT username FROM admins WHERE id='$from_id'";
             $run_user = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$user_query);
             $from_username = $run_user['username'];

             echo "<p><strong>$from_username</strong></p></br>";
        }
}else{
    header('Location: messages.php');
}
?>
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   object given on line 6

Here's line 6 & as you can see I have already included the *$con* which is my database connection.

> while($row_messages = mysqli_fetch_array($con,$run_messages)){

Comment: `printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);`

Comment: If not solved, then Please post your database connection code.

Comment: Plus you having typo in second query `$form_id !=$from_id` it would be `SELECT username FROM admins WHERE id=$form_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)**

> mysqli_fetch_array ( mysqli_result $result [, int $resulttype =
>   MYSQLI_BOTH ] )

First parameter is `Specifies a result set identifier returned by mysqli_query()` and second parameter is `result type`

Remove connection as first parameter

It would be

```
$row_messages = mysqli_query($run_messages,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Your code is open for sql injection better use bind statement

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

To check error in your connection and query use

```
/* check connection */

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if (!$mysqli->query("SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

In second query you use

`$user_query = "SELECT username FROM admins WHERE id='$from_id'";`

> TYPO here

```
$form_id !=$from_id
```

Change this to

`$user_query = "SELECT username FROM admins WHERE id=' $form_id'";`

Comment: The 2 errors appear: : mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given on line 5 & mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given on line 6

Comment: Have your problem solved using `$row_messages = mysqli_query($run_messages,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
` ??

Comment: You have typo in second query `$form_id !=$from_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['hash'])&&!empty($_GET['hash'])){
        $hash = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_GET['hash']);
        $message_query = "SELECT from_id, message FROM message WHERE hash='$hash'";
        $run_messages = mysqli_query($con,$message_query);
        while($row_messages = mysqli_fetch_array($run_messages, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $from_id = $row_messages['from_id'];
             $message = $row_messages['message'];

             $user_query = "SELECT username FROM admins WHERE id='$from_id'";
             $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $user_query);
             $run_user = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
             $from_username = $run_user['username'];

             echo "<p><strong>$from_username</strong></p></br>";
        }
}else{
    header('Location: messages.php');
}
?>
```

Essentially mysqli_fetch_array has one required parameter which is the **result of a query** and an optional query of the result type.  `$run_messages` is the result of the first query and will be used for the execution of `mysql_fetch_array` and `MYSQLI_ASSOC` is the optional type that you will be using so you can access the values in $row_messages like you do.

Read [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for more information.

Also, please remember to escape user valued with mysqli_escape_string before allowing the data to be queried into the database. This reduces the chance of SQLi.

Comment: Correct typo of second query in your code too `$form_id!=$from_id`

Comment: I was just going off what was given in the OP. I have changed it though.